# GlassFish Dynamic JDBC Pool

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish, glassfish-3, connection-pooling

I have MySQL DBMS with 3 Database

- config
- master1
- master2

A JSF 2.1 application do the login with specific username on config DB then do some query and obtain the name of DB on which do the connection.

Now with 2 simple databases the solutions are simple:

1. join `master1` and `master2` with config and create a single mono database with relations... Possible, but there is the request to separate user data - so discard.
2. Create `n` pools in Glassfish then use the appropriate pool.

Actually I'm using this solution but if I have master 0...1000, I have to create all of them manually, which is quite time consuming.

I'd like to:

1. connect as the usual to config
2. retrieve the DB name
3. check if resource (with same name) exists

   1. if it doesn't exist; create it
4. Now use it

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029975/686036.

I believe you would be able to use the RESTful API to do what you want.

1. Connect to the config *// not sure if you would need to do this step anymore*
2. Retrieve the database name *// this is for you to do*
3. Check if resource exits given a name

   ```
   curl LIST http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/
   ```

   This gets you the list of all jdbc connection pools available.  It would then be left to you to find if the one you are looking for is found.

   1. If resource doesn't exist, create it

      ```
      curl -X POST -H "X-Requested-By: GlassFish REST HTML interface" 
      -d id=jdbc/myjdbcresource -d connectionpoolid=DerbyPool 
      http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/jdbc-resource
      ```

      This would then be sample code to create a resource on your server through a cURL request.
4. Use resource *// from the application.*

#### See also :

- [Oracle's Using REST Interfaces to Administer GlassFish Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/general-administration.htm#gjipx)
- [Oracle's Dotted Names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/dotted-names.htm#GSRFM00268)

Comment: @user1594895 Yes, that is basically what I found out.  Since modifying the `domain.xml` file directly requires a reboot, but making the changes through the API call, simply puts them in effect.  It worked for me. Not sure it would be considered a hack since it's a JSR to include a RESTful API on java servers.